# How can can I get jQuery Mobile 1.4.1 structure only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

Im new to jQuery Mobile. I am trying to get jQuery structure only. For example, if I want to style any part of the links or inputs. So is there any way I can just use the structure and then style however I want?

Comment: Use jquery mobile theme roller to build your own themes.

Comment: @GolezTrol jQuery doesn't, but jQuery Mobile does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Jquery mobile and have just been doing some of this myself.  You can personalise the general theme at themeroller
http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/

Save that to your directory and then link your webpage to it.  Instructions are on the site.
It will tell you to link using something like:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
```

Which as you can see the bottom one links to 'structure' only so is a bit different.  Then you add in your own normal stylesheets after these to customise & override things further.